# What does angular $watch do when no return value from the function it monitor

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

All:

I am pretty new to Angular, when I tried to understand how [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) works, there is some code in its source like:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    _debounce || (_debounce = $timeout($storage.$apply, 100, false));
});
```

From Angular Scope Doc:

> $watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
>
> Expression that is evaluated on each $digest cycle. A change in the
> return value triggers a call to the listener.
>
> string: Evaluated as expression
>
> function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.

Both ways need some return value to trigger a listener, but in this example, there is no return value nor listener, so **I kinda wondering what this code do**?

Or **if anyone could briefly talk about how ngStorage works**?

Thanks